# Choose k distinct and increasing index from n

Tags: r, algorithm, sum, combinations

Consider the formula in the following picture, where j and n are fixed integers. It is clear that n cannot be large. I am considering using n=10. The key feature is to find all distinct j-tubes (i_1 < ... < i_j) out of n. Is there an easy way to achieve this in `R`, please? Could anyone help me, please?
[image: photo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), selecting `j` from `n` without regard to order. Of course, the mapping of the elements of the combination to *i<sub>1</sub>*…*i<sub>j</sub>* will require sorting them (in order to satisfy the constraint *i<sub>1</sub>* < … < *i<sub>j</sub>*), but this is actually how [`combn()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/combn.html) returns its results by default:

```
jtubes <- function(j,n) combn(n,j);
jtubes(3,5);
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2     3
## [2,]    2    2    2    3    3    4    3    3    4     4
## [3,]    3    4    5    4    5    5    4    5    5     5
```

`combn()` returns the result as a matrix with one combination per column, but you can change that to per row with a single call to [`t()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html).